# How to export models from admin page with username rather than user id?

Tags: python, django

I have a participant model in models.py Django as the following:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Participant(models.Model): 
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    score = models.FloatField(default=0)
    completed_study = models.BooleanField(default=False)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

and I want to be able to export all the data from the admin page, so under the admin.py I added the following

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Participant
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as BaseAdmin
from import_export.admin import ImportExportModelAdmin
from import_export import resources
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserResource(resources.ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username')

class UserAdmin(BaseAdmin, ImportExportModelAdmin):
    resource_class = UserResource


class ParticipantAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    list_display = ['user', ]
    readonly_fields = ('created_at', 'updated_at',)

class ParticipantAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    pass 
admin.site.register(Participant, ParticipantAdmin)
admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

I am able to export the data from the participant model, but I want under the user field to display the actual username rather than the id. How can I do that? is that even doable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to add:

```
fields = ('user__username')
```

to represent the relational field

Answer (score 1):

```
class UserResource(resources.ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username')

    def dehydrate_username(self, user):
        return user.username
```

The import-export library provides a dynamic method based on relation fields so you can return data whatever you want for specific field using `dehydrate_<field>`

Comment: I am already able to export the data from the user model with the username,  why should I add the dehydrate method for the user class? shouldn't I add that for the participant?